# Call End Notification in Windows Phone and Launching App

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does Windows Phone (any version) provide call start/end notifications? And if yes is it possible to launch an application when a call ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible at this time. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059656/windows-phone-7-events-triggered-on-phone-call-connect-and-phone-call-disconne) other question where the OP wants to do something similar.