# Is there any way to monitor phone call info on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I know you can make a call using PhoneCallTask, but is there any way to trigger an action while making the phone call?

For example, set a timer and make a sound when it's been 1 or 2 minutes on the call.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059656/windows-phone-7-events-triggered-on-phone-call-connect-and-phone-call-disconne

Answer (score 3):

No, applications are not allowed access to the phone directly.

The only access your application has with the core phone features is via Launchers and Choosers. See MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769556(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: The app is tombstoned while the call is in progress, right? If a call timer is the goal, perhaps a web service that can be fired when PhoneCallTask is launched that sends an SMS after a specified time. Granted, this wouldn't take into account dialing and connection.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe Yes, the application is tombstoned during the call. An SMS wouldn't help any as currently Windows Phone apps can't intercept SMS messages.

Comment: No, but it would be a means of displaying an alert to the user outside of the app. Maybe its a network thing, but on my phone I can receive SMS while on a call.